# Can we use Change Data Capture inside the same Salesforce Org

Tags: apex, trigger

Please help me to get knowledge,

For Account I added to Change Data Capture and created ChangeEvent trigger named with AccountChageTrigger(obj: AccountChangeEvent) to do an operation. In AccountChageTrigger I am passing IDs to a ChageTriggerHelperclass to do update on related contacts. Will it work?.

For me, the AccountChangeEvent is not triggering I added a DML operation to test in both AccountChangeEvent and ChageTriggerHelperclass for testing nothing is triggering. Did I miss any permission? or I have missed anything please let me know how to get this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is data capture enabled for an account object in setup?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled.

Comment: Post your trigger code so we can see what's going on at the code level